# Unable to load Image Icon to a button in Netbeans

Tags: java, imageicon

```
ClassLoader cldr = ImageDisplayTest.class.getClassLoader()
URL url = cldr.getResource("resources/wifi.png");
jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(url));
```

This is the code I wrote to load an Image Icon. Can you suggest what I need to do, because I get an error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: ImageDisplayTest.class.getClassLoader

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
ImageDisplayTest.class.getResource("/resources/wifi.png");
```

That assumes that your `resources` directory is on the classpath.

**UPDATE:**

As you didnt show us the  directory structure, we assumed that you know what you are doing and `resources` in your path is actual package. But as you mentioned that it is a Maven project, a light bulb apears above my head. I bet that your "resources" is a part of maven directory structure am I right?

In this case, your path to resource will be simple "/wifi.png" assuming that that image exists and is not nested into some other packages.

For the sake of clarity, if this does not work, post your directory structure - screenshot from eclipse will be fine.

Comment: Is there any substitute for ImageDisplayTest? I want to load an icon to a button.

Comment: @SwagatYadawad Use the name of the class containing that line of code.

Comment: Does the backslash in the beginning matter?

Comment: @SwagatYadawad yes it matters, you will get NPE without it. But anyway all depends on your classes hierarchy and if your `resources` is included into app itself or it lays next to eg. runnable jar.

Comment: Does it make any difference if this is a maven project?

Comment: Initially it was a normal java project. I created a new Maven project and copied all the files from there to the new project. Is there something I need to do after I copy all the files?

Comment: @SwagatYadawad I already wrote what you should do - include structure directory do the question

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5FFVTcNvJp8LWVuSmVVUHh5Y0U this is the structure.

Comment: @SwagatYadawad if this is real structure AND this is typical maven project with default project structure, then I was right and path would be `/imagename` without `resources` part, so `/wifi.png` should be sufficient.

Comment: jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/wifi.png")));
I wrote this, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initiate a `ClassLoader` object, just use `getResource()` method of your class like this:

```
 URL url = ImageDisplayTest.class.getResource("resources/wifi.png");
```

Comment: Is there any substitute for ImageDisplayTest? I want to load an icon to a button.

Comment: Just use any class name where `resources` folder is in the same folder with it

Comment: It shows that I have to create a class named ImageDisplayTest to proceed. Is there any other standard class to be used?

Comment: I changed ImageDisplayTest to ImageIcon, and now the line "jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(url))" gives a NullPointException.

Comment: No, it is not about standard java class here, the image path is relative to the location of the class you chose, it could be any class of your own defined classes, maybe the current class itself `getClass().getResource("resources/wifi.png");`

Comment: I added the "getClass().getResource("resources/wifi.png"), but I'm still getting NullPointException in the next line, I'll still check and get back.

Comment: the directory "resources" and the java file are in the same directory, is it ok????

Comment: your `url` is null because `getResource()` would return null if the resource/image is not found in the specified path, so make sure to put the resource folder in your classpath, not the java files folder

Comment: put the resources folder just beside the `.class` file of your class

Comment: @SwagatYadawad its because you have to start with `/`

Comment: I started with a "/" and also  the resources folder is beside the .class file, but unfortunately it isnt working.

Comment: Does it make any difference if this is a maven project?